# spring RestTemplate return maybe raw content , can't read

Tags: resttemplate

```
        String feed = "https://www.swift.org/atom.xml";

        RestClient rc = RestClient.create();
        String s = rc.get().uri(feed).retrieve().body(String.class);

        System.out.println(s);
```

spring RestTemplate  return  maybe  raw content    ,  can't read .

run , we will see .

is the content is compressed  ?

[image]